# Move record from first Django model to second and then delete it from first

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I want to move a record from `NewUsers` model to `PendingUsers` model on the button click. After moving, the record should be removed(deleted) from `NewUsers` model.

Here's the models:

```
class NewUser(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete = models.CASCADE, default=1)
    newuser_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    newuser_company = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    newuser_mobile = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    newuser_designation = models.CharField(max_length=50) 
    newuser_image = models.ImageField(upload_to='userprofile_pics/users/', blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.email

class PendingUsers(models.Model):
    pendinguser = models.OneToOneField(NewUser, on_delete = models.CASCADE, default=1)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.pendinguser.newuser_name
```

On Button click, the code to move the record is:

```
query_user = get_object_or_404(NewUser, id=id)
pendingUser = PendingUsers()
pendingUser.pendinguser = query_user
pendingUser.save()
```

And to delete it from NewUsers:

```
NewUser.objects.filter(id=id).delete()
```

It is successfully moving the record to PendingUsers. But as soon as I'm deleting it from NewUser, it is automatically deleted from PendingUser as well.

Can anybody help me out with this about how to achieve this successfully? Do I need to change my PendingUsers model?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: "on_delete = models.CASCADE" remove linked model, so yes, you need change model.

Comment: usually you can change status of user (without delete), or you need copy all fields from New User to Pending Users to avoid lose data.

Comment: @VelikiiNehochuha then how should I design the model?

Comment: @VelikiiNehochuha I think changing the status will work out. Thanks!

Comment: @PrachiSharma   https://stackoverflow.com/a/58241855/8138584

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of taking that approach, you can add a `user_status` field to your `NewUser` column, like this:

```
class NewUser(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete = models.CASCADE, default=1)
    newuser_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    newuser_company = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    newuser_mobile = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    newuser_designation = models.CharField(max_length=50) 
    newuser_image = models.ImageField(upload_to='userprofile_pics/users/', blank=True)
    user_status = models.CharField(max_length=10, default='new')
```

Now when the button is clicked, you simply change the value of `user_status`:

```
query_user = get_object_or_404(NewUser, id=id)
query_user.user_status = 'pending'
query_user.save()
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I did the same as mentioned by @VelikiiNehochuha in comments earlier. It's working now as I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest modify your `NewUser model` and add new `Boolean` field `is_pending`.

```
class NewUser(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete = models.CASCADE, default=1)
    newuser_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    newuser_company = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    newuser_mobile = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    newuser_designation = models.CharField(max_length=50) 
    newuser_image = models.ImageField(upload_to='userprofile_pics/users/', blank=True)
    is_pending= models.BooleanField(max_length=10, default=True)
```

---

```
query_user = get_object_or_404(NewUser, id=id)
query_user.user_status = False
query_user.save()
```

***NOTE ::*** -

you can change the `default values and logic` according to your requirement for `is_pending` field.

---

Comment: Thanks for the answer. As answered previously, it works now.